# Flutter: Print PDF in a printer using IP address without preview

Tags: flutter, printing, thermal-printer

I need to print a pdf data in a wifi thermal printer from my android app. I have the ip address of the printer already, so I need to send the pdf data to the printer and print the data without the android preview

I have tried using the [**Printing**](https://pub.dev/packages/printing) package but cannot implement the system. Help me, thanks in advance

My code:

```
await Printing.layoutPdf(
    onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async => pdf.save());
```

Comment: Can you give some code and errors that you might've faced?

Comment: @KJ can you show me a sample code to how to do that?